# How to make ngClick toggle between 0 and 1 instead of true and false?

Tags: angularjs

I want to give an element toggle functionality, and so far I have something along the lines of this:

```
<span ng-click="rule.activated = !rule.activated" 
      ng-class="{active:rule.activated}">
    Toggle
</span>
```

But the data I want to post back, after whichever value the user has specified, should be between `0` and `1` instead of `true` and `false`. Currently, if the initial value of `rule.activated` is for example `0`, and after the `span` element is clicked, it switches to `true` (which the back-end doesn't handle correctly, so I have to avoid it).

I've tried this, but it seems like a syntax error:

```
ng-click="rule.activated = (int) !rule.activated"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a conditional Statement

```
ng-click="rule.activated = rule.activated ? 1 : 0"
```

The part after the '?' is the true-part, the part after the ':' is the false-part.

This would be the whole Statement

```
<span
    ng-click="rule.activated = rule.activated ? 1 : 0" 
    ng-class="{active:rule.activated == 1}">
    Toggle
</span>
```

Comment: I had to do this ---- ng-click="rule.activated = rule.activated==0 ? 1 : 0"

Answer (score 1):

Change the type of rule.activated to a number

$scope.rule.activated = 0;

Then use the conditional statement

```
<span ng-click="rule.activated = rule.activated == 0 ? 1 : 0"
    ng-class="{active:rule.activated==1}">

    {{rule.activated}}

    Toggle
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best and safest way would be to simply write a function which handles this and call the function inside ngclick.